# VBA/EXCEL Split excel file on specific row if cells value are not equal

Tags: vba, excel

I have little problem with split excel file. My case is that I have file with for instance 10k rows and I'd like split every 1k row, but the most important is second statement which should say that if we are on 1k row and the value of cell in row b is equal to previous cell then we should split file when they won't be equal.

For now I can split excel file and save it, but I don't know how to write if statement for loop which I have.
My if statement:

```
 If counter = 1500 And require.Value <> require.Offset(-1).Value Then
```

One more thing **MAX rows in file** must be 1500 without header

Here is my code:

```
Sub SplitRowsToFiles()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim saveFile As String
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim WR As Range
Dim last As Double
Dim counter As Double
Dim part As Double
Dim name As String

Dim string1 As String
Dim string11 As String
Dim string12 As String
Dim Taba() As String
Dim value1 As Double
Dim header As Range
Dim require As Range


On Error Resume Next

xTitleId = "Export To TXT"

Set require = Range("b140:b14000")

Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, "A2:C11", Type:=8)
Set header = Application.Selection
Set header = Application.InputBox("Header range", xTitleId, "A1:C1", Type:=8)
Set WR = WorkRng
saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    last = .Cells(1, 1).Row + .Rows.Count - 1

  End With
  MsgBox "ab" & last & "ab"

string1 = WorkRng.Address()

Taba() = Split(string1, ":")

string11 = Mid(Taba(0), 4)
string12 = Mid(Taba(1), 4)

value1 = Val(string12) - Val(string11) + 1


For counter = 0 To last
If counter = 1500 And require.Value <> require.Offset(-1).Value Then

part = part + 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
Set WR = Union(header, WR)
WR.Copy
wb.Worksheets(1).Paste
name = saveFile & part & ".xls"
wb.SaveAs Filename:=name, FileFormat:=xlExcel8, CreateBackup:=False
wb.Close
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set WorkRng = WorkRng.Offset(value1)
Set WR = WorkRng
counter = counter + value1
Else
End If
Next


End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Side note: You should avoid using `On Error Resume Next` because this is bad practice (see [VBA Good Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/5411/error-handling#t=201704241252392743835)). Anyway reading the entire guide would be a good idea.

Comment: Nice article! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following will split the original file into a number of 'split' files such that each 'split' file will have at least a 'blkSize' of rows including the header (presently 'blkSize' is set to 1000 as per your problem statement) and no more than 'blkSize' + 'maxLimit' rows (maxlimit is presently set to 500) - so no more than 1500 rows including the header.

I assuming your the first 'hdrSize' rows in the original file are the header you want to copy to each of the files as the first several rows ('hdrSize' is presently 1).

If you have no duplicates in column 'B' then you'll get 'split' files of 'blkSize' rows except for the last one which will just contain the remaining rows.  If you have duplicates in column 'B' at the point where the splitting occurs you'll get a variable size file size from 'blkSize' to 'blkSize'+'maxLimit' rows.  Since each of the split files could be of a different length depending on the # of duplicates in column 'B', you won't know before running the code how many files will get generated.

You can set each of these variables: 'hdrSize', 'blkSize' and 'maxLimit' as you require at the top of the code.

```
Option Explicit


Sub SplitRowsToFiles()

  Dim hdrSize As Integer: hdrSize = 1
  Dim blkSize As Integer:  blkSize = 1000 - hdrSize
  Dim maxLimit As Integer: maxLimit = 500

  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
  Dim saveFile As String, name As String
  Dim WR As Range, header As Range

  Set wrkSht = ActiveSheet
  Set header = wrkSht.Rows("1:" & hdrSize)

  saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename

  Dim last As Integer
  With wrkSht.UsedRange
    last = .Rows.Count
  End With

  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
  Dim limit As Integer, part As Integer
  part = 0
  i = hdrSize + 1 ' skip the header

  Do While True

    j = i + blkSize - 1
    If j <= last Then
      ' process from blkSize to blkSize+maxLimit rows
      limit = j + maxLimit
      Do While Cells(j, "B") = Cells(j + 1, "B") And _
           j < limit And j < last
        j = j + 1
      Loop
    Else
      ' otherwise process up to the last row
      j = last
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

     Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add 
     Set WR = wrkSht.Rows(i & ":" & j)

     header.Copy wb.Worksheets(1).Rows("1:" & hdrSize)
     WR.Copy wb.Worksheets(1).Rows(hdrSize + 1)

     part = part + 1
     name = saveFile & part & ".xls"
     wb.SaveAs Filename:=name, FileFormat:=xlExcel8, CreateBackup:=False
     wb.Close

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    i = j + 1
    If i > last Then Exit Do

  Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Work wonderful! But I have one question about header, could you explain me how is it work? 
I choose range for instance A1:J3 and I change 'prevBlkRow' and when I run macro it's cut header to first line.

Comment: I found answer for that :) u chose other way to union header and body, these two lines:
 header.Copy wb.Worksheets(1).Rows(1)
     WR.Copy wb.Worksheets(1).Rows(2)

Comment: everything works fine now, but i have two problem: the maximum copy rows should be 1500 not more and second problem i tried copy columnwidth but is take ages i used two copy options:
.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: Ok, I solved one problem with copy column width header.Copy
    wb.Worksheets(1).Rows(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths and several minor. BUT i have still problem how to have less than or equal 1500 rows in excel

Comment: See my EDIT above.

Comment: Note that there's still one condition that the above code doesn't handle: the case where you have a "B" column duplicates that exceed 'blkSize' in #.

Comment: Yep, and that case it's most important to solve. Because after this change which u wrote i edit not really change how it's works. The main problem is when in row 1500 is the same value as 1501 and 1499 then script should back to the first equal value and split file on this row. So i'm not sure why this -> 'And j < limit' don't split file in right place

Comment: Also I tried if statement in loop, but Idk how to cut record to the last which is not equal. I put this in loop but it split excel every 1500 row  If j > maxLimit Then Exit Do
    Else
    j = j + 1
    End If

Comment: See the revised solution based on these comments.

Comment: in 2 different file I have rows with the same numbers in column B. It's look like that this script cut file on 1500 row and second statement doesn't matter. To be clear the goal is have file with maximum 1500 rows and the same "unique" numbers can't be in two different files

Comment: Here is an example how this file look like https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19SGHZSBrNbteMbCeZYqsq9g9ddsnwFKrdSsHA51olQg/edit?usp=sharing and where we have to split it

Comment: What you're saying is that the 1K limit isn't a hard one - you can have file sizes less than 1K so long as duplicates aren't split between files?  If that's the case you could add another do loop which will go backwards to see where this limit is.  But if you have more than blkSize+maxLimit rows of duplicates you have two conflicting requirements.  Unfortunately I can't help beyond this point - if need be you can re-post another question.

Comment: But if you have more than blkSize+maxLimit rows of duplicates you have two conflicting requirements" i wont have that kind of situation because duplicates line is max 300-600
Please look at last rows of flie which i share on google sheet

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I think you're just missing a counter that reaches your limit (1500) and resets to zero (subject to column B not matching). I've used `pcounter` (p for 'partial')

Try this:

```
Sub SplitRowsToFiles()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim saveFile As String
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim WR As Range
Dim last As Double
Dim counter As Double
Dim pcounter As Double
Dim part As Double
Dim name As String

Dim string1 As String
Dim string11 As String
Dim string12 As String
Dim Taba() As String
Dim value1 As Double
Dim header As Range
Dim require As Range


On Error Resume Next

xTitleId = "Export To TXT"

Set require = Range("b140:b14000")

Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, "A2:C11", Type:=8)
Set header = Application.Selection
Set header = Application.InputBox("Header range", xTitleId, "A1:C1", Type:=8)
Set WR = WorkRng
saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    last = .Cells(1, 1).Row + .Rows.Count - 1
End With

MsgBox "ab" & last & "ab"

string1 = WorkRng.Address()

Taba() = Split(string1, ":")

string11 = Mid(Taba(0), 4)
string12 = Mid(Taba(1), 4)

value1 = Val(string12) - Val(string11) + 1

pcounter = 0

For counter = 0 To last
    If pcounter > 1500 And require.Value <> require.Offset(-1).Value Then
        pcounter = 0
        part = part + 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
        Set WR = Union(header, WR)
        WR.Copy
        wb.Worksheets(1).Paste
        name = saveFile & part & ".xls"
        wb.SaveAs Filename:=name, FileFormat:=xlExcel8, CreateBackup:=False
        wb.Close
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set WorkRng = WorkRng.Offset(value1)
        Set WR = WorkRng
        counter = counter + value1
    Else
        pcounter = pcounter + 1
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False    

End Sub
```

Comment: unfortunately it's not working, this split file like my code without comparing values

Comment: I used your comparison of `require.Value <> require.Offset(-1).Value` - perhaps that's not quite right?